# Give weights to matching fields

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

Have a problem with Sphinxql. I try to match several fields and give each a weight.

```
select id
       ,item
        ,param1
        ,param2
        ,module_id
        ,param2_id
        ,date_change
        ,custom_rank
        ,weight() as rank
        ,in(site, 336935152)
                        and if(date_from, date_from, 1578400079) <= 1578400079
                        and if(date_to, date_to, 1578400079) >= 1578400079
                        and ((((module_id = 3674251022)and(param1_id = 455881287)and(param2_id = 4196041389)))) as cond1
        ,if(date_to, date_to, 1578400079) date_to_nvl
        ,if(date_from, date_from, 1578400079) date_from_nvl
        from index
        where MATCH('@(title,body) (search query)')
        limit 0, 500
        option max_matches = 500
        ,field_weights=(title=99999, body=1)
```

But weight doesn't matter. Even if I give `99999` weight to title and `1` to body and vice versa, query result doesn't change. My goal is to make sphinx, firstly match title and after body.

UPD: `packedfactors()` query result

```
+------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | weight() | packedfactors()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1055 |  1000631 | bm25=631, bm25a=0.650515, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=1, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.158041, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=5, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.790203, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=3, min_best_span_pos=3, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), word0=(tf=6, idf=0.158041)   |
| 1056 |  1000631 | bm25=631, bm25a=0.650515, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=1, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.158041, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=5, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.790203, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=3, min_best_span_pos=3, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), word0=(tf=6, idf=0.158041)   |
|  242 |  1000627 | bm25=627, bm25a=0.649095, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=1, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.158041, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=4, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.632162, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), word0=(tf=5, idf=0.158041)   |
|  813 |  1000627 | bm25=627, bm25a=0.649095, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=1, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.158041, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=4, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.632162, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), word0=(tf=5, idf=0.158041)   |
|  815 |  1000627 | bm25=627, bm25a=0.649095, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=1, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.158041, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=4, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.632162, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), word0=(tf=5, idf=0.158041)   |
| 1054 |  1000627 | bm25=627, bm25a=0.649095, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=1, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.158041, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=4, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.632162, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), word0=(tf=5, idf=0.158041)   |
|  334 |  1000621 | bm25=621, bm25a=0.647014, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=1, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.158041, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=3, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.474122, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), word0=(tf=4, idf=0.158041)   |
|  335 |  1000621 | bm25=621, bm25a=0.647014, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=1, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.158041, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=3, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.474122, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), word0=(tf=4, idf=0.158041)   |
|  510 |  1000621 | bm25=621, bm25a=0.647014, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=1, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.158041, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=8, min_best_span_pos=8, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=3, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.474122, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=10, min_best_span_pos=10, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), word0=(tf=4, idf=0.158041) |
| 1057 |  1000621 | bm25=621, bm25a=0.647014, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=1, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.158041, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=3, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.474122, min_idf=0.158041, max_idf=0.158041, sum_idf=0.158041, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=1, wlccs=0.158041, atc=0.000000), word0=(tf=4, idf=0.158041)   |
+------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Use PACKEDFACTORS() to understand what's going on, there may be different reasons why your ranking doesn't change.

Below you can see an example which shows how to use it and that for example for some documents stats are only exposed for one field of 2, because the keywords were found only in one field.

```
MySQL [(none)]> select id, weight(), packedfactors() from index where match('@(subject,body)manticore search') limit 5 option ranker=expr('sum(lcs*user_weight)*1000+bm25'), field_weights=(subject=1,body=10)\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             id: 67020137501
       weight(): 20614
packedfactors(): bm25=614, bm25a=0.67905319, field_mask=2, doc_word_count=2, field1=(lcs=2, hit_count=3, word_count=2, tf_idf=0.30208117, min_idf=0.07970884, max_idf=0.14266349, sum_idf=0.22237234, min_hit_pos=5, min_best_span_pos=17, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=2, wlccs=0.22237234, atc=0.02281057), word0=(tf=1, idf=0.14266349), word1=(tf=2, idf=0.07970884)
*************************** 2. row ***************************
             id: 67020139037
       weight(): 20614
packedfactors(): bm25=614, bm25a=0.67905319, field_mask=2, doc_word_count=2, field1=(lcs=2, hit_count=3, word_count=2, tf_idf=0.30208117, min_idf=0.07970884, max_idf=0.14266349, sum_idf=0.22237234, min_hit_pos=74, min_best_span_pos=86, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=2, wlccs=0.22237234, atc=0.02281057), word0=(tf=1, idf=0.14266349), word1=(tf=2, idf=0.07970884)
*************************** 3. row ***************************
             id: 67164506141
       weight(): 20601
packedfactors(): bm25=601, bm25a=0.67105567, field_mask=2, doc_word_count=2, field1=(lcs=2, hit_count=2, word_count=2, tf_idf=0.22237234, min_idf=0.07970884, max_idf=0.14266349, sum_idf=0.22237234, min_hit_pos=105, min_best_span_pos=105, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=1, lccs=2, wlccs=0.22237234, atc=0.02248834), word0=(tf=1, idf=0.14266349), word1=(tf=1, idf=0.07970884)
*************************** 4. row ***************************
             id: 60360225821
       weight(): 11653
packedfactors(): bm25=653, bm25a=0.70337892, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=2, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.08168077, min_idf=0.08168077, max_idf=0.08168077, sum_idf=0.08168077, min_hit_pos=3, min_best_span_pos=3, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=0, lccs=1, wlccs=0.08168077, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=4, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.60435468, min_idf=0.15108867, max_idf=0.15108867, sum_idf=0.15108867, min_hit_pos=61, min_best_span_pos=61, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=0, lccs=1, wlccs=0.15108867, atc=0.00027331), word0=(tf=4, idf=0.15108867), word1=(tf=1, idf=0.08168077)
*************************** 5. row ***************************
             id: 59004972573
       weight(): 11645
packedfactors(): bm25=645, bm25a=0.70018470, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=2, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.08168077, min_idf=0.08168077, max_idf=0.08168077, sum_idf=0.08168077, min_hit_pos=11, min_best_span_pos=11, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=0, lccs=1, wlccs=0.08168077, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=3, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.45326602, min_idf=0.15108867, max_idf=0.15108867, sum_idf=0.15108867, min_hit_pos=56, min_best_span_pos=56, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=0, lccs=1, wlccs=0.15108867, atc=0.00005638), word0=(tf=3, idf=0.15108867), word1=(tf=1, idf=0.08168077)
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MySQL [(none)]> select id, weight(), packedfactors() from index where match('@(subject,body)manticore search') limit 5 option ranker=expr('sum(lcs*user_weight)*1000+bm25'), field_weights=(subject=10,body=1)\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             id: 60360225821
       weight(): 11653
packedfactors(): bm25=653, bm25a=0.70337892, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=2, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.08168077, min_idf=0.08168077, max_idf=0.08168077, sum_idf=0.08168077, min_hit_pos=3, min_best_span_pos=3, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=0, lccs=1, wlccs=0.08168077, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=4, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.60435468, min_idf=0.15108867, max_idf=0.15108867, sum_idf=0.15108867, min_hit_pos=61, min_best_span_pos=61, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=0, lccs=1, wlccs=0.15108867, atc=0.00027331), word0=(tf=4, idf=0.15108867), word1=(tf=1, idf=0.08168077)
*************************** 2. row ***************************
             id: 59004972573
       weight(): 11645
packedfactors(): bm25=645, bm25a=0.70018470, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=2, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.08168077, min_idf=0.08168077, max_idf=0.08168077, sum_idf=0.08168077, min_hit_pos=11, min_best_span_pos=11, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=0, lccs=1, wlccs=0.08168077, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=3, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.45326602, min_idf=0.15108867, max_idf=0.15108867, sum_idf=0.15108867, min_hit_pos=56, min_best_span_pos=56, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=0, lccs=1, wlccs=0.15108867, atc=0.00005638), word0=(tf=3, idf=0.15108867), word1=(tf=1, idf=0.08168077)
*************************** 3. row ***************************
             id: 52749413289
       weight(): 11631
packedfactors(): bm25=631, bm25a=0.69566667, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=2, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.14696111, min_idf=0.14696111, max_idf=0.14696111, sum_idf=0.14696111, min_hit_pos=1, min_best_span_pos=1, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=0, lccs=1, wlccs=0.14696111, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=2, word_count=2, tf_idf=0.23519781, min_idf=0.08823670, max_idf=0.14696111, sum_idf=0.23519781, min_hit_pos=23, min_best_span_pos=23, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=2, exact_order=0, lccs=1, wlccs=0.14696111, atc=0.00378523), word0=(tf=2, idf=0.14696111), word1=(tf=1, idf=0.08823670)
*************************** 4. row ***************************
             id: 69779455599
       weight(): 11609
packedfactors(): bm25=609, bm25a=0.68568671, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=2, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.15835057, min_idf=0.15835057, max_idf=0.15835057, sum_idf=0.15835057, min_hit_pos=11, min_best_span_pos=11, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=0, lccs=1, wlccs=0.15835057, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.08304220, min_idf=0.08304220, max_idf=0.08304220, sum_idf=0.08304220, min_hit_pos=32, min_best_span_pos=32, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=0, lccs=1, wlccs=0.08304220, atc=0.000000), word0=(tf=1, idf=0.15835057), word1=(tf=1, idf=0.08304220)
*************************** 5. row ***************************
             id: 53174602295
       weight(): 11605
packedfactors(): bm25=605, bm25a=0.67905343, field_mask=3, doc_word_count=2, field0=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.08168077, min_idf=0.08168077, max_idf=0.08168077, sum_idf=0.08168077, min_hit_pos=9, min_best_span_pos=9, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=0, lccs=1, wlccs=0.08168077, atc=0.000000), field1=(lcs=1, hit_count=1, word_count=1, tf_idf=0.15108867, min_idf=0.15108867, max_idf=0.15108867, sum_idf=0.15108867, min_hit_pos=35, min_best_span_pos=35, exact_hit=0, max_window_hits=1, min_gaps=0, exact_order=0, lccs=1, wlccs=0.15108867, atc=0.000000), word0=(tf=1, idf=0.15108867), word1=(tf=1, idf=0.08168077)
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tried to execute your query, got the result, but which factors are the most important here?

Comment: Updated my question, added query result

Comment: It depends on your ranker. If you look at my example I used ranker=expr('sum(lcs*user_weight)*1000+bm25') which is the default one. If you used the same then the only 3 important factors you should look at are: lcs, your per-field weights and bm25. For example for doc with id 60360225821 from my list the final weight is calculated like this (1*1+1*10)*1000+653=11653 where lcs=1/1, weights=1/10 and bm25 = 653.